# FB page nativeoffers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Graph Api to get native offers from a page. I have created an offer on a page and I can see it on page "timeline".
I am trying to get the offres through Graph Api explorer using this endpoint:

427459880988759/nativeoffers

According to the documentation this should return the native offers for the page with id 427459880988759. Instead it returns empty data.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you grant `manage_pages` permission?

Comment: No I haven't If I understand correct it is not neccessary as long as I want to read data not to manipulate

Comment: @Christoforos I am facing the same issue. Any updates on this.